# How to prevent solidification of mastic in nozzles

Tags: cartridge, mastic

Using mastic or adhesives in cartons or cartidges that are squeezed out by a handgun, the nozzle is of paramount importance.

Problem is, going back several days, weeks, or months later, the mastic has gone hard in the nozzle. It's often fine still inside the gun, but the nozzle, even if it had a screw-on cap, is full of solid, which often won't come out happily. Silicone, as it stays malleable, is the only one to easily remove, so the nozzle gets re-used, but what ways are there to ensure any nozzle doesn't just fill, solidify, and get thrown away?

This isn't a problem for tradesmen, who will get through many cartridges a week, so will use the same nozzle on the next tube, thus ending up with several spare unused.

Comment: Remove nozzle, screw on a lid from toothpaste tube, if it fits.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler - then, presumably, clear out the nozzle. Messy!

Comment: I used one tube of silicon for 1.5 years, on and off. Didn't use a nozzle. Water vapour makes it set - stored in a dry car also.

Answer (score 1):

I push a nail or screw into the nozzle, has to fit tightly though.

Usually work for a week or more, but after that I have to dig the nozzle out or fit a new nozzle to continue using the cartridge.

It will never keep forever, had some old cartridges that had never been used or opened and they had just gone solid so there **is** a shelf life...

Comment: Shelf life is often several months, dependent on what's in the tube, and a well fitting screw may (and has) worked for a week or so. And can be unscrewed - the longer the better). It's after that week or so...

Answer (score 0):

I just put adhesive tape on the tip of the nozzle.

This isn't perfect, but the cartridges last a lot longer this way than with the screw-on cap.

Comment: The cartridge lasts as long as I need, unless it gets left for a year or more. I'm more concerned with the remnants left in the *nozzle*, which solidify, not allowing that nozzle to be re-used. Tape or even the screw on tip for the nozzle is pretty useless at stopping the stuff in the nozle solidifying.